# Работа с формами (обмен данными ) в Visual C++ CLR

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте , начал создавать проект в Visual Studio 2012 C++ CLR .Сделал как вычитал в интернете создал форму через addItem -> UI -> WindowsForms . Получил естественно два файла заголовочный и cpp файл. В заголовочном файле описан сам класс формы , все настройки и так далее , более менее все понятно . В сппшнике записал точку старта и описал меин .

```
#pragma once
#include "cnvFunc.h"
#include "multiLevel.h"
#include "addDepForm.h"

namespace MultiLevelList {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  Exit;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  copyrightToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  exitToolStripMenuItem1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  mainMenu;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  copyrightToolStripMenuItem1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  exitToolStripMenuItem;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  actionsToolStripMenuItem;

    protected:

    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->Exit = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
            this->mainMenu = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->actionsToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
            this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Exit
            // 
            this->Exit->Location = System::Drawing::Point(287, 182);
            this->Exit->Name = L"Exit";
            this->Exit->Size = System::Drawing::Size(109, 62);
            this->Exit->TabIndex = 0;
            this->Exit->Text = L"Exit";
            this->Exit->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->Exit->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::Exit_Click);
            // 
            // menuStrip1
            // 
            this->menuStrip1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::CornflowerBlue;
            this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(2) {this->mainMenu, this->actionsToolStripMenuItem});
            this->menuStrip1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
            this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
            this->menuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(701, 24);
            this->menuStrip1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->menuStrip1->Text = L"menuStrip1";
            // 
            // mainMenu
            // 
            this->mainMenu->DropDownItems->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(2) {this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1, 
                this->exitToolStripMenuItem});
            this->mainMenu->Name = L"mainMenu";
            this->mainMenu->Size = System::Drawing::Size(46, 20);
            this->mainMenu->Text = L"Main";
            // 
            // copyrightToolStripMenuItem1
            // 
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1->Name = L"copyrightToolStripMenuItem1";
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(127, 22);
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1->Text = L"Copyright";
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::copyrightToolStripMenuItem1_Click);
            // 
            // exitToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"exitToolStripMenuItem";
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(127, 22);
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Exit";
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::Exit_Click);
            // 
            // actionsToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->actionsToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"actionsToolStripMenuItem";
            this->actionsToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(59, 20);
            this->actionsToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"Actions";
            // 
            // copyrightToolStripMenuItem
            // 
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"copyrightToolStripMenuItem";
            this->copyrightToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(32, 19);
            // 
            // exitToolStripMenuItem1
            // 
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem1->Name = L"exitToolStripMenuItem1";
            this->exitToolStripMenuItem1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(32, 19);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(701, 482);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Exit);
            this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
            this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Mobile repair service \"MobiRepair\" ";
            this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
        addDepForm depFrm;
    private: System::Void Exit_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 Application::Exit();
             }
private: System::Void copyrightToolStripMenuItem1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         MessageBox::Show("Some text","Hello",MessageBoxButtons::OK,MessageBoxIcon::Information);
         depFrm.Show();
         depFrm.Owner = this;

         }
private: System::Void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             Application::Exit();

         }
};

}
```

MyForm.cpp

```
 #include "MyForm.h"
        #include "addDepForm.h"

        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

        [STAThread]
        void Main(array<String^>^args) {
            Application::EnableVisualStyles();
            Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MultiLevelList::MyForm form;
            Application::Run(%form);

        }
```

Все события по нажатиям на кнопку автоматически создаются в заголовочном файле.
У меня уже есть протестированный алгоритм в консольном приложении. Нужно реализовать интерфейс. 
Есть много вопросов :
1. Где нужно описывать основной алгоритм программы ? Все действия по нажатию на кнопки и прочее объявляются как приватовские в заголовчном файле формы. Можно ли как-то перенести описание в отдельный файл ? 
2. Где описывать объявление всех переменных , объектов класса и прочих ?
3. Создал новую форму , с текстовыми полями для ввода и кнопками подтверждения . Как связать с основной формой , чтобы можно было получать введенные данные из формы ? 
4. Не будет ли автоматически вызван деструктор для выделенной памяти через new например по нажатию на кнопку ?

Спасибо за ответы заранее.